# Next.JS jsx suggestion not working in VS-Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, autocomplete, jsx

When i create new fresh Next.js app and use JavaScript and open it using vs code, in .jsx files, suggestions not working as shown in the image, the props suggestions of any component not showing.
[Suggestions not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3APcL.png)
[Props Suggestions not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1hPP.png)
But when i create it and use TypeScript it works.

I deleted all `settings.json` file and reset all vs code settings but i doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to follow these methods

- Check for VS Code Updates
- Clear VS Code Cache
- install required extensions